# htaccess : combining permanent domain change and stripping of www

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I I use the code below to strip the www from my (new) domain. Now I want to redirect the old domain tot the new one too. Can't get it to work. Is it possible to do both?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.skiweather\.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://skiweather.eu/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rewrite *anything* to your new domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=skiweather.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://skiweather.eu/$1 [L,R=301]
```